# Not able to tree shake lodash in a Webpack, TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, webpack, tree-shaking

my goal is to tree shake `lodash` (amongst others) in my `webpack.prod.js`. Here are my configuration files. For completeness sake I will also include the `webpack.dev.js`, `webpack.common.js`, `tsconfig.json` and `package.json`:

`webpack.common.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|obj)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.glsl$/,
                loader: 'webpack-glsl-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                loader: 'tslint-loader',
                options: { failOnHint: true }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.ts'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Production'
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

`webpack.dev.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const JarvisPlugin = require("webpack-jarvis");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|obj)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.glsl$/,
                loader: 'webpack-glsl-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                loader: 'tslint-loader',
                options: { failOnHint: true }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.ts'
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ title: 'urknall-core dev' }),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ analyzerPort: 8888 }),
        new JarvisPlugin({ port: 1337 }),
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    }
};
```

`webpack.prod.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            test: /\.js($|\?)/i,
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: true
            }
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            debug: false
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }),
    ]
});
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./types",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "bla",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "types": "./dist/types/",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "watch": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/gl-matrix": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.104",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.4",
    "@types/webgl2": "^0.0.2",
    "@types/webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.18",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2",
    "webpack-glsl-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack-jarvis": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gl-matrix": "^2.4.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.5"
  }
}
```

With this configuration the `app.bundle.js` results in a file of 507 KB and the `app.bundle.js.map` is 1.6 MB. If I do not uglify the build output I can see that the entire lodash library is being written into the file. I am also seeing some other functions from i.e. `gl-matrix` being written to the file, although I am not even using them.

Also I run a `webpack-bundle-analyzer` in development and the output does not differ from production. Only the budle file is ~1.4 MB instead of 1.6 MB because of minification.

[image]

I am loading `lodash` only twice in the entire project, like:

`import { some, find, cloneDeep } from 'lodash';`

No more `lodash` functions are ever used. Why does `Webpack` inflate my `app.bundle.js`?

Is there any problem with my configuration?

Comment: try with [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) instead, it should work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the existing export style of the standard `lodash` package you have two options for solving this:

1. Move to a lodash package that uses exports in a way that will socket directly into your import pattern. As mentioned by @alex-rokabilis in a comment, one available package for this is [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es)
2. Update your imports to work the exports used by the standard `lodash` package. If you look at [lodash's npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) you can see that they provide support for cherry picking specific method from paths.

   ```
   import some from 'lodash/fp/some';
   import find from 'lodash/fp/find';
   import cloneDeep from 'lodash/fp/cloneDeep';
   ```